# changing properties of multiple buttons at once using for loop in visual c#

Tags: c#, winforms, button

In visual c#, I have built a win form in which I have 10 buttons
I have the following code for `button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)`:

```
button1.Text = "A".toString();
button2.Text = "B".toString();
button3.Text = "C".toString();
...
button9.Text = "I".toString();
```

But the code is too lengthy. Is there any way I can do this inside a loop?
Something like this:

```
char x = 'A';
for(int i = 1; i<10;i++,x++)
{
    button[i].Text = x.toString();
}
```

Pls help

Comment: "A" is already a `string`. No need to add `ToString` to it . ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You could add your `Button` controls to a list and iterate the list.

```
int charIndex = 65;
foreach (Button b in buttonList)
{
   b.Text = new String((char)charIndex, 1);
   charIndex++;
}
```

If you don't have nested controls and you want to get all the buttons to a list, you could do

```
List<Button> buttonList= Controls.OfType<Button>().ToList();
```

then iterate as above.

Comment: Another thing that might be more readable is to use char[] characters = "ABCDEFGHILM".ToCharArray() and access the array to get the correct character.

Comment: @FabioMarcolini - That's a good idea.